# How create a drop-down list in Jenkis pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, devops

I created a Jenkins pipeline that creates a backup of an Oracle Database and storage in a GitLab repository and, if necessary, execute a rollback. I want to create a drop-down list with a file in this GitLab repository that can select exactly what backup I want to execute. This is in a **Stage block** of Jenkins pipeline. It is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a dropdown list within a `stage` block in Jenkins, because the pipeline variables have already been determined by that point (from the `properties([ parameters ([])])` blocks).

You can create a select list in the parameters block, but that wouldn't allow you to dynamically select from a list of files. Alternatively you could create a bunch of manual jobs based on a list of files, and kick off just the ones you need, but this doesn't seem like a CI/CD pattern that will scale well. You may want to figure out a better way to perform this job.

Comment: Thanks for your response!, I will use parameters then.